# How can i include type safety in mu query parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have service where i need to send query parameters dynamically.

**METHOD SERVICE**
So i have this method in my `AuctionService`.

```
getBids(id:number, params?: any) {
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params});
}
```

From my component when i send the query parameters

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
  let queryParams = {
      filterSupplierName: 'sds',
      filterBidAwardStatus: ['Awarded', 'Ignored']
    }

 this.getAuctionService
    .getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(id, queryParams)
    .subscribe((data) => {
...
```

it makes dynamically the  GET url to be like so

https://some-url/api/22222/bids?filterSupplierName=sds&filterBidAwardStatus=Awarded&filterBidAwardStatus=Ignored

NOW I WANT TO MAKE TYPE SAFETY IN MY query params, so from component when i try to send for example some property which key or values is not correct, to show some compilation error.

So i need to have
`filterSupplierName of type string OR filterBidAwardStatus OF type array of string`.

So when i try that

```
export interface IBidsFilter {
  filterSupplierName: string;
  filterBidAwardStatus: string[];
}
getBids(id:number, params?: IBidsFilter) {
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params});
}
```

i get error No overload

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'ITest' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'ITest' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'ITest'
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried

```
getBids(id:number, params?: ITest) {
    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (value !== undefined) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
          httpParams = httpParams.set(key, value);
        }
        else {
          httpParams = httpParams.set(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
      }
    });
    return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params: httpParams});
  }
```

Now i have type safety from my component

**THIS IS GOOD**

```
let queryParams: ITest = {
      filterSupplierName: 'sds',
      filterBidAwardStatus: ['Awarded', 'Ignored']
 }

 this.getAuctionService
    .getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(id, queryParams)
    .subscribe((data) => {
```

**THIS THROWS ERROR**

```
let queryParams: ITest = {
      filterSupplierName: 'sds',
      someInvalidProp:222
 }
```

but the problem now is that when the get URL is hitted it looks like

https://some-url/api/22222/bids?
filterSupplierName=sds&filterBidAwardStatus=%5B%22Awarded%22,%22Ignored%22%5D

But i need to look like

https://some-url/api/22222/bids?filterSupplierName=sds&filterBidAwardStatus=Awarded&filterBidAwardStatus=Ignored

How can i achive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST SOLUTION**

You can extend your interface from `HttpParams`, Like this:

**IBidsFilter Interface**

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface IBidsFilter extends HttpParams {
  filterSupplierName: string;
  filterBidAwardStatus: string[];
}
```

**The only problem is that you can have the fields wich types are `string | string[]`**

**SECOND SOLUTION: IGNORE THIS ONE**

I have fixed the type issue connected with the queries with this workaround

```
getBids(id:number, params?: IBidsFilter) {

  return this.http.get(
       this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', 
       {params:  params as any}  
    // params as any is a workarround
  );

  }
```

It will fix your error: **Type 'TypeName' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | and etc'.**

And your function will be type safety

Comment: thanks for your comment. Is there any other way ? I am not big fan of any if you know otbher way it would be great

Comment: Btw why is this error - why with extending HttpParams it works ?

Comment: But it does now work in the typescript when i set the interface - with the type that extends from HttpParams

Comment: the error is because of the type `HttpParams` the realization of `HttpParams` is that all of the values can be a string or arrays of strings. The extend word is telling us that we are keeping all of the functional of parent class and adding new ones for the sub class, so it means the type of your subclass can be checked by the parent class. Let me know if have any questions

Comment: Then how can i make my object to be the type of interface i want ? Can you please edit the answer because it is not working when i extend from HttpParams

Comment: it should work. just tried on my side